# How to return name values of empty fields in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this piece of code that validates an html form and highlight empty fields with red borders.

What I want is to be able to return the name values of empty input fields so I can output them.

```
var isValid = $('input, textarea').not('input:disabled').filter(function() {

    return !this.value;

}).css('border-color', 'red').length == 0;

if(isValid){
    console.log('Ok');
}else if(!isValid){
    console.log($(this).attr('name') + 'must not be empty');
}
```

When there are no empty fields the first part works well, but when there are empty fields I was expecting to get the name values of those inputs in the console. But I keep getting **undefined**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can use `map()`

```
var isValid = $('input, textarea').not('input:disabled').filter(function() {    
    return !this.value;    
}).css('border-color', 'red')

var names = isvalid.map(function(){
    return this.name;
}).get()
```

Comment: Do you think `return !this.value;` will work? Shouldn't it be `return !this.value.length;`

Comment: @AlonEitan will work fine since empty string is falsy

Comment: @AlonEitan but both would fail with a  space(s) as value....might be better as `return !this.value.trim()`

Comment: Yup, but since a space will pass the `required` validation, then i'll leave it to the OP to decide who it should be handled

Comment: @charlietfl It works! but I realize two of the names are empty strings. What might that implies?

Comment: implies names aren't set properly

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks very much, do u think the  disabled inputs even though not selected might be behind the empty strings issue?

Comment: @charlietfl the funny thing is that the array that is returned contained all empty input fields and I can confirm it from the HTML form. But the extra two empty strings is what I don't understand.

Comment: provide a [mcve] preferably in a sandbox like jsfiddle,plunker, codepen etc

Comment: @charliefl Oh OK.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that `isValid` is boolean (`.length == 0`). You need to get the filtered elements like this:

```
var isValidEl = $('input, textarea').not('input:disabled').filter(function() {

    return this.value.length == 0;

}).css('border-color', 'red');
```

And then, change the condition to:

```
if(!isValidEl.length){
    console.log('Ok');
} else {
    isValidEl.each(function() {
        console.log($(this).attr('name') + ' must not be empty');
    });
}
```

Exmaple:

```js
var isValidEl = $('input, textarea').not('input:disabled').filter(function() {

    return this.value.length == 0;

}).css('border-color', 'red');

if(!isValidEl.length){
    console.log('Ok');
} else {
    isValidEl.each(function() {
        console.log($(this).attr('name') + ' must not be empty');
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="" name="emptyInput">
<textarea name="emptyTextaria"></textarea>
<textarea name="nonEmptyTextaria">HELLO</textarea>
<input type="text" value="HELLO" name="nonemptyInput">
```

Comment: I'm getting isValidEl.each is not a function.

Comment: And If I may asked, isValid is a boolen, then why do you access it's length property? because true and false will always have a length value which will be true at the end for both cases.

Comment: Yes, I didn't use your variable name, just only the logic inside.